# How to choose the right focal length lens for my photodetector?

Tags: optics

I wanted to know how to choose the right focal length lens for my silicon carbide photodetector which has a peak response of 315nm and an active area of 25mm^2 such that I can mount that lens on my photodetector to reject any ambient light and allow only UV light to pass through it. Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Do you want to image something with the detector or just collect as much light as possible?